# Permission denied error when I run ionic build ios command?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

When I ran

> ionic build ios

I get the following error.

sh: /Users/imac/Documents/TGF_IOS/node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts: Permission denied

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:build" "--"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/imac/Documents/TGF_IOS/npm-debug.log
```

Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have got the solution.

First step check if you have permission (read/write) to the project folder.

Secondly, run this command with sudo,

```
sudo npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

This will install latest app-script and wll fix the issue.